# How do I put Youtube videos in my Roku Channel?

Tags: html, video, youtube, roku

I've been able to use videos uploaded to my personal website AND IT WORKED! but how can I use YouTube videos on my roku channnel? Also how do I use live Youtube videos as well?
For Example I want to use this video URL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0DPdy98e4c how could I do that in my Roku Channel?

Here is some of my code WHICH HAS WORKED for mp4 videos uploaded to my personal website.

```
<item sdImg="I put my image sd url here -- no problem" hdImg="I put my hd mage url here -- no problem">
    <title>My Title </title>
            <contentId>10001</contentId>
            <contentType>Talk</contentType>
            <contentQuality>HD</contentQuality>
            <streamFormat> have tried "mp4" "hls" "mkv" "ism" etc...</streamFormat>
            <media>
                    <streamQuality>HD</streamQuality>
                    <streamBitrate>1500</streamBitrate>
                    <streamUrl> tried to use a youtube url here and video doesnt play once app is developed</streamUrl>
            </media>
            <synopsis>Some random synopsis to put here</synopsis>
            <genres>Technology</genres>
            <runtime>10</runtime>
    </item>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I stream Youtube videos in my Roku Channel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296963/how-can-i-stream-youtube-videos-in-my-roku-channel)

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube T.O.S. says you can't.